# Nginx and Gunicorn in different servers

Tags: nginx, amazon-ec2, gunicorn

I have gunicorn running on a server. What I want to do is to put nginx in front of it on a different server. But for that I need to send the request from the nginx to the gunicorn machine.

How can I do that?

By the way the servers are EC2 instances from Amazon.

Answer (score 0):

This is really a trivial thing to do and is well covered in Nginx documentation, which you should read.

The key steps are:

- Spin up the Nginx machine and install Nginx
- Assign the Nginx machine an elastic IP
- Create an Nginx configuration that includes a proxy_pass so requests are passed through to the private IP of the GUnicorn instance (not the public IP)
- Update DNS to point your A / CNAME record at the instance
- Ensure the security groups are appropriate, so the Gunicorn machine isn't in the public subnet and doesn't have a generally accessible public IP unless you have a good reason for it to need one

Comment: Thanks a lot to the quick question. Do a proxy_pass to the private IP is enough? Shouldn't it be pointing to the sock created by gunicorn?

Comment: If it was on the same machine you could use a socket, but I suspect that on a separate machine you have to address it by IP. I can't say for sure, try it out with the socket first, if that doesn't work do it by IP.